# Eclipse organize folders without using packages

Tags: java, android, eclipse

When designing stand-alone application it was customary of me to just use packages to differentiate between what types of classes should be where.  This helped in finding classes and organizing enums from views and listeners, etc.

However, now that I have been developing a library, it doesn't make sense to use the packaging structure because I don't want to make all these enums and views public.  They should be protected such that the user of the library does not have unnecessary access and visibility to these useless components.

But, in order to do that it would seem that I would have to have them in the same package, which would of course now just cause complete congestion of classes in one place without organization.

Is there a way or a plugin perhaps that would let me organize these classes? That would be of great help.  I had seen a couple questions with responses such as 'it can't be done', but I would assume a plug-in out there would help and I'm sure plenty of people have come across this.

Maybe there is an easy solution...

Comment: So to understand you: You want to organize yu source files into folders but they all should stay in the same package? Do you think that a user of the library has no problems having hundreds of classes in one package whil you have this problem?

Comment: That is what I was asking yes. The library user will probably only have between 5-10 visible classes in all when said and done.  The other hundred are only what I see as the developer of the library.

Comment: Definitely use packages. If you don't want the library users to know about some packages, then don't include them into the documentation. Or mark them as "for internal use only". If well organized, classes going with each other should belong in the same package, and only some of them would be visible to other packages anyway.

Comment: Sounds as though to get the type of structure that I would want I would have to do it with careful organization and access modifiers. Guess I see it as a fault that we cannot just create locally accessible classes throughout packages of a library that we will create as a developer while restricting external access.  It seems the only way we get cross-package communication is making classes public.